# Getting an error when I check a check box

Tags: vb.net

I have a pretty basic program as an assignment (I'm a beginner so it's still tricky for me) that requires you to enter a decimal value, and have a check box do a calculation and then show the result in different labels. I'm constantly getting errors when I checkthe check box with no values added.

```
Private Sub chkGST_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkGST.CheckedChanged
    'get txtDollarAmt*const dGST (0.07D) display lblGSTOutput. txtDollarAmt+dGST, display lblTotalOutput

    Dim dAmt As String

    dAmt = Decimal.Parse(txtDollarAmt.Text)

    If chkGST.Checked = True Then
        lblGSTOutput.Text = dAmt * dGST

    End If



End Sub
```

Comment: what error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to parse the text(Convert it to Decimal), check if it is null.
Use Try Catch block.

instead of this line.

```
dAmt = Decimal.Parse(txtDollarAmt.Text)
```

Use this-

```
Try
   dAmt = Decimal.Parse(txtDollarAmt.Text)

Catch e As FormatException

End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dAmt As Decimal 

If Decimal.TryParse(txtDollarAmt.Text, dAmt) Then
    If chkGST.Checked = True Then
        lblGSTOutput.Text = dAmt * dGST
    End If
End If
```